# RadialGradientPaint Equivalent in Android

Tags: java, android, image

I am drawing a radial gradient circle on an image like this

[image]

I have java code for this

```
private void drawRadialGradientCircleJava(String imagePath, double posX, double posY, float radius, String outputPath) throws IOException{
    BufferedImage city = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

    BufferedImage mask = new BufferedImage(city.getWidth(), city.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = mask.createGraphics();
    Color transparent = new Color(255, 0, 0, 0);
    Color fill = Color.RED;
    RadialGradientPaint rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(
            new Point2D.Double(posX, posY),
            radius,
            new float[]{0f, 0.75f, 1f},
            new Color[]{transparent, transparent, fill});
    g2d.setPaint(rgp);
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight()));
    g2d.dispose();

    BufferedImage masked = new BufferedImage(city.getWidth(), city.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    g2d = masked.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, masked.getWidth(), masked.getHeight());
    g2d.drawImage(city, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstAtop);
    g2d.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(masked,"png", new File(outputPath));
}
```

I want to do same thing in Android, I have an image view in which I have an image, now I want to touch a point in image and draw this transparent circle around that point

I have following Android code as well but id doesn't draw anything on the image

```
  private void drawRadialGradientCircleAndroid(ImageView imageView, float posX,
                                                 float posY, float radius) throws IOException {

        RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(posX, posY, radius, Color.TRANSPARENT,
                Color.TRANSPARENT, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setDither(true);
        p.setShader(gradient);

        Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawCircle(posY, posX, radius, p);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);

    }
```

Please help how can I achieve this in Android.

Answer (score 0):

We should migrate this to the answer boxes.

OP has basically got it here- and in fact the OP's revised  [gist](http://gist.github.com/galaxyfeeder/7026165)  is brilliant.

Some general tips regarding the first attempt in the question:

1) In `protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)`:

- `width = w;` there is no reason why you can't call `getWidth()` when you require this. The reason it's advisable is because the `View`'s internal width is set quite late after `onMeasure`. Consequently, `onDraw` may be the next time you want a most up to date version, so use the getter there.
- `mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`. Creating a bitmap is an expensive and memory intensive operation. Unless you want to write a bitmap to a file, or send it to a `BitmapDrawable` for an `ImageView` or something, you don't need to do this. Especially with effects drawn onto the UI with android's `graphics` library.
- `mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);` followed by a draw operation onto the new canvas. This is never needed. And yet I've seen it (not work) in many code bases and attempts. I *think* it's the fault of an old stack overflow post that got people doing this so that they could transform a canvas on a custom view without effecting the drawing onto the rest of the canvas. Incidentally, if you need this, use `.restore()` and `.save()` instead. If you see `new Canvas`, **be suspicious**.

2) `onDraw(...)`:

- *Yes*, you need to avoid doing things in `onDraw`, like, creating objects, or any heavy processing. *But* you still need to do the things in `onDraw` you need to do in `onDraw`!
- **So here you simply need to call** : `canvas.drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)` with arguments as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).
- This really isn't that sinful for `onDraw`. *If you're worried about calling this too much*, as might be the case if your entire button is animating across the screen, you need to use [hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) available in later API versions, as will be detailed in an article called [Optimizing the View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html); very helpful reading if you're using lots of custom drawn views.

3) **That pesky radial gradient**. The next issue you had is that you quite rightly created your paint in an `init`method so that the object creation was off the draw. But then quite rightly it will have `IllegalArgumentException`ed (I think) on you because at that stage the `getHeight()` of the view was 0. You tried passing in small pixel values- that won't work unless you know some magic about screen sizes.

This isn't your issue as much as the annoying view cycle at the heart of Android's design patterns. The fix though is easy enough: simply use a later part of the view's drawing process after the `onMeasure` call to set the paint filter.

**But** there are some issues with getting this right, namely that sometimes, annoyingly, `onDraw` gets called before the point at which you'd expect it. The result would be your paint is null and you wouldn't get the desired behavior.

I have found a more robust solution is simply to do a cheeky and naughty little null check in the `onDraw` and then *once only* construct the paint object there. It's not strictly speaking optimal, but given the complex way in which the `Paint` objects hook up with Android's graphics native layer better than trying to straddle the paint configuration and construction in many frequently called places. And it makes for darn clearer code.

This would look like (amending your gist):

```
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            if (mPaint == null) {
                mPaint = new Paint();
                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                mPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2,
                        getHeight() / 3, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, TileMode.MIRROR));
            }
            width = getWidth();
            height = getHeight();
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, height / 3, mPaint);
        }
```

So note a few changes- I think from your description you want the two colours swapped round in the arguments, also don't forget to center the center of your gradient in your view: `width/2` and `height/2` arguments.

Best of luck!

Comment: It is not working as I want. It is just drawing a black circle not a transparent one. I have tried with Color.Transparent as well. Could you guide me with my code. What I have to change there?